# Which algorithms require functors to be pure functions?

Tags: c++, functor

Generally the standard requires functors to be pure functions because algorithms are allowed to copy their functors to their heart's content. However, there are some algorithms (e.g. `find_if`) for which no sane implementation would be doing any form of functor copying.

Can we rely on this?

Comment: By "pure function" do you mean a `const` function? Regardless I don't know the answer to this but I suspect it's buried in the new standard somewhere.

Comment: Title says "free functions", text says "pure functions". No algorithm requires free functions, just any callable object.

Comment: What's the question? In the FDIS, `for_each` requires the function object to be only move- but not copy-constructible.

Comment: @GMan: Sorry, fixing that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* what you're trying to ask is which functors need to be stateless due to being copied at arbitrary times.

I can't think of any algorithms that require free functions to be used, but most/all certainly require the *object itself* to not hold state. What you *can* do is have the object have a reference to a state object that's held outside the algorithm call. Any copy of the functor can then modify that state object appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by "pure function?"

If you mean "function pointer", then no; every standard algorithm can take function objects as well as function pointers. Yes, they must be *copyable*, but a functor that is copyable is still a functor.

If you mean "copyable", then yes. The standard library requires that the type given to algorithms be copyable. If your functor isn't copyable, you can use a `boost::reference_wrapper<T>` to wrap your non-copyable object in a copyable container that acts as a reference. Note that this template was added to C++0x as `std::reference_wrapper<T>`.